# How do I find a commit hash for a repository that has been archived

Tags: macos, git, diff

I have a directory that is an export from git. I would like to find the commithash of the code that was exported.

My first inclination is something like:

```
for each commit in repo:
  if diff(commit, export) is empty:
     return commit.hash
```

But I am not quite sure how I would go about this in reality, or if there is an easier way

Comment: You used `git archive` to produce the export?  If so, what was the exact command?

Answer (score 0):

If you used `git archive` you can recover the commit from the contents of the archive:

> git archive behaves differently when given a tree ID versus when given
>   a commit ID or tag ID. In the first case the current time is used as
>   the modification time of each file in the archive. In the latter case
>   the commit time as recorded in the referenced commit object is used
>   instead.  Additionally the commit ID is stored in a global extended
>   pax header if the tar format is used; it can be extracted using git
>   get-tar-commit-id. In ZIP files it is stored as a file comment.

So, depending on how you created the archive, you can use the modification time of a file in the archive to find the commit just before that time or directly access the commit ID.

If you don't have the archive then look at the creation/modification dates for the files/archive.  Then, back in the repository use:

```
git log --before=<date> -n 1
```

to see one commit before the relevant date.

Comment: i dont have the original archive, and I doubt it was created using `git-archive`

Comment: Then check the file/archive create/modification dates and see if you can discern something from that.  See updated answer.

Comment: it seems that the dates have been modified.  Basically, I ma installing a package via `npm` and want to find the commithash for the version I am installing, it is not using `git archive` and it seems to change the dates.  is there a way with `git diff` to do this?